# How can i make nulleable Byte[]

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, nullable

Hi everyone I can't take a null value for my image property I have this error:

> Implicit conversion from data type nvarchar to varbinary(max) is not allowed. use the convert function to run this query.

This is my prop class:

```
namespace testhopital
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
    using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;

    public partial class UserProfile
    {
        public UserProfile()
        {
            this.webpages_Roles = new HashSet<webpages_Roles>();
        }

        public int UserId { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "User name")]
        public string UserName { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Prenom")]
        public string UserSurname { get; set; }
         [Display(Name = "Email")]
        public string UserEmail { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Date Naissance")]
        [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        public Nullable<System.DateTime> UserBirthday { get; set; }
        [Column(TypeName = "image")]
        [Display(Name = "Votre Photo")]
        public byte[] UserPicture { get; set; }
         [Display(Name = "Adresse")]
        public string UserAdress { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "numero de tlephone")]
        public string UserPhone { get; set; }
          [Display(Name = "Description")]
        public string UserDescription { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Date de creation")]
        public Nullable<System.DateTime> UserCreateAcount { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Date de modification")]
        public Nullable<System.DateTime> UserLastUpdate { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> RoleId { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "User password")]
        [DataType(DataType.Password)]
        public string password { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Confirm password")]
        [Compare("password", ErrorMessage = "mot de passe pas valider")]
        [DataType(DataType.Password)]
        public string confirmPassword { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<webpages_Roles> webpages_Roles { get; set; }
        public virtual webpages_Roles webpages_Roles1 { get; set; }
    }
}
```

and my controller:

```
  [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Register(UserProfile register, HttpPostedFileBase image2)
    {


        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {

            try
            {
                register.UserPicture = new byte[image2.ContentLength];
                image2.InputStream.Read(register.UserPicture, 0, image2.ContentLength);

            }
            catch (Exception)
            {

                register.UserPicture = null;
            }

            WebSecurity.CreateUserAndAccount(register.UserName, register.password, new
                          {

                              UserSurname = register.UserSurname,
                              UserEmail = register.UserEmail,
                              UserBirthday = register.UserBirthday,

                              UserPicture = register.UserPicture,
                              UserAdress = register.UserAdress,
                              UserPhone = register.UserPhone,
                              UserDescription = register.UserDescription,
                              UserCreateAcount = DateTime.Now,


                          },true);

            return RedirectToAction("Login", "AccountHopital");
        }
        return View(register);

    }
```

I have error if I make a null Image.
I need to make image to null value not a byte[0]

Comment: write public byte?[] UserPicture;

Comment: i have 4 errors in my controller :  Argument 1: cannot convert from 'byte?[]' to 'byte[]' in " register.UserPicture = new byte[image2.ContentLength];"

Comment: you change datatypes of variables  wherever you are using this UserPicture

Comment: yes but i will have problem to read a array byte here Error 1 The best overloaded method match for 'System.IO.Stream.Read(byte[], int, int)' has some invalid arguments (image2.InputStream.Read(register.UserPicture, 0, image2.ContentLength);)

Comment: then better to make check for if(image2 != null)

Comment: In your database the `UserPicture` column is `nvarchar`, why is it that? Is it holding a Base64Encoded string?

Comment: i have the some error:/

Comment: it a nvarchar(Max), Null

Comment: Use Convert method while selecting for this column

Comment: @OussAma What do you mean null able btye[]? you meant each entry of the array be null able? If so, have you tried byte?[] in your code?

Comment: yes the some errorr the problem is in the web.security function

Answer (score 4):

Arrays, including byte arrays, are nullable by default. If you initialize the byte array in this way, an exception will throw when image2 is null:

```
register.UserPicture = new byte[image2.ContentLength];
```

The exception will throw because image2 is null, and it therefore does not have a "ContentLength" property to get. Instead, this should work:

```
if(image2 != null) 
{
   register.UserPicture = new byte[image2.ContentLength];
   image2.InputStream.Read(register.UserPicture, 0, image2.ContentLength);
}
```

That way, you'll only initialize a byte array if you have an image.

**Edit:** I read too quickly. I see that you're using exception handling to catch this, which is not a good practice. Exceptions should only be used for true exception cases.

The real issue here most likely has to do with the dynamic handling of a byte[] parameter passed to the `WebSecurity.CreateUserAndAccount()` function. You may want to convert the byte array to a base 64 string: `Convert.ToBase64String(register.UserPicture)`, when creating the user. When it's time to read the image from the database, you can use `Convert.FromBase64String(model.UserPicture)` to retrieve the byte array from the base 64 string.

Comment: Implicit conversion from data type nvarchar to varbinary(max) is not allowed. Use the CONVERT function to run this query.     Ligne 80 :                 Ligne 81 :                 WebSecurity.CreateUserAndAccount(register.UserName, register.password, new
Ligne 82 :                               {

Comment: so byte arrays is not nulleable by default ..!

Comment: @OussAma no absolutely not, use the byte?[] just as vivek says, and convert it back to (byte) when you need to

Comment: byte?[] represents an array of nullable bytes. It is also a nullable array, as arrays are nullable by default.

I've edited my original post with something that will hopefully help with the data type exception.

Comment: @OussAma nullable byte arrays are absolutely possible, and are absolutely nullable by default.  You understand that that error message indicates the column is the wrong type?

Comment: yes you are right , the problem it's not with the byte[]  .. the problem is with web.security the framework can't make a null array

Comment: maybe the best it s to create another controller for manage account and another taable "profile" for examle

Comment: At a database level, a byte array is a VARBINARY, so if the library casts the byte array to a string for storage in a VARBINARY database column (I'm not sure if he library is doing this), you'll get an exception. You'll also get an exception if you try to store the byte array in a NVARCHAR (string) column without converting it to a string. You'll either need to store the byte array in a VARBINARY database column, or you'll need to convert it to a string format (like base 64) for storage in an NVARCHAR column.